# Why is ngOnChange being called twice in a child component with only one input variable

Tags: angular, ngonchanges

I have a child component that takes one input variable.  The child component makes use of ngOnChanges so that any changes to the input variable triggers a change.

Everything is working fine, however, I see that ngOnChanges gets called twice every time the parent component loads.

Sample code:

Parent Component

```
  <div *ngIf="(devWidth > 576)">
     <app-child-component [inputParam]="paramValue"></app-child-component>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="!(devWidth > 576)">
     <app-child-component [inputParam]="paramValue"></app-child-component>
  </div>
```

Child Component HTML

```
  <div>
     {{inputParam}}
  </div>
```

Child Component TS

```
  @Input() inputParam;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('ngOnChanges called with changes value: ', changes)
}
```

Comment: From the [Angular Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence) documentation: `ngOnChanges` is "Called before `ngOnInit()` (if the component has bound inputs) and whenever one or more data-bound input properties change."

Comment: @DM It is also being called twice even when there is a change to the property even if ngOnInit is not called.

Comment: I've created quick demo on stackblitz and `ngOnChanges` is called only once. Can you update project to better reflect your situation and post it  here?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g21nq2?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: I added more detail it: https://angular-ivy-bqzj8x.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

My solution was

```
<app-child-component *ngIf="paramValue" [inputParam]="paramValue"></app-child-component>
```